# Wpf Modern UI Metro Chart Atualizar Gráfico

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho o gráfico abaixo onde o primeiro load funciona normalmente, mas quando faço uma pesquisa e altero a lista ele continua com a série anterior.

Ex: no primeiro load tenho 8 items na lista e ele mostra ok. De acordo com uma pesquisa populo novamente com 21 items porém o gráfico continua mostrando os 8 items anteriores.

```
<chart:ClusteredColumnChart
    x:Name="chtEvolucaoDiaria"                 
    Style="{StaticResource MinimalChartStyle}"
    ChartTitle="Evolução Diária"    
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="3"
    Width="auto"
    Height="400"
    Background="#444444"
    Foreground="White"
    Palette="{StaticResource Cores}" 
    ChartSubTitle="" 
    >
</chart:ClusteredColumnChart>
```

No codebehind populo ele desta forma:

```
chtEvolucaoDiaria.Series.Clear();

ChartSeries series = new ChartSeries();
series.Name = "dc" + dia;
series.DisplayMember = "Categoria";
series.ValueMember = "Valor";
series.SeriesTitle = dia.ToString();
series.Foreground = Brushes.White;

series.ItemsSource = ListaDcEvolucaoDiaria;

chtEvolucaoDiaria.Series.Add(series);
```

***Edição***

Aparentemente alterar a ordem das seguintes linhas funciona:

De:

```
series.ItemsSource = ListaDcEvolucaoDiaria;

chtEvolucaoDiaria.Series.Add(series);
```

Para:

```
chtEvolucaoDiaria.Series.Add(series);

series.ItemsSource = ListaDcEvolucaoDiaria;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente alterar a ordem das seguintes linhas funciona:

De:

```
series.ItemsSource = ListaDcEvolucaoDiaria;

chtEvolucaoDiaria.Series.Add(series);
```

Para:

```
chtEvolucaoDiaria.Series.Add(series);

series.ItemsSource = ListaDcEvolucaoDiaria;
```